# Illustrator CS5 stroke moves anchor points

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a shape. I have successfully created the shape but when i try to add a stroke it moves my anchor points and the stoke becomes non symmetric around the joining part.

Have any ideas why is that?
[image]

the image on the left is without the stroke and the right with the stroke added. as you can see the "bridge" its not uniform. i don't understand why.

Comment: Try to paste a better screenshot. The screenshot of the shape with highlighted anchor points will help too.

Comment: i added a screenshot

Comment: is snap to grid switched on?

Comment: Atleast i can not replicate the problem

Comment: it is off. i turned on from view>snap and still same result

Comment: Can you post a file? Also can it be a optical illusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance that you have selected "Align to pixel grid" option. You can find it in "Show options" of the Transform panel. In the drop-down menu of the panel there is also an option "Align new objects to pixel grid". Uncheck it.

If you do not want to turn it off, there is a hack for this bug. Apply stroke with 2px wide, select "Align stroke to inside" in the Stroke panel, then change it to 1px.

Comment: thank you, that was the problem with the "Align new objects to pixel grid"